# About Cahn - Hilliard equation solution uniqueness

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

The uniqueness of the solutions of the Cahn - Hilliard nonlinear PDE
$$\dfrac{\partial c}{\partial t}=\nabla\dot{}(M\nabla\mu)$$ has been proved for many form of the chemical potential $\mu$. What happens if the mobility $M$ is not constant and depends on $c$? Is it possible to prove the uniqueness of the solution also in some of this cases? Thanks.

Comment: For the record, at time of writing this question has attracted a vote to close as "unclear what you're asking". I strongly disagree with this reason given